# Angular Toggle class only on single div

Tags: javascript, angular

data

```
test = [
    {
      "test1": {
            "qq": ["qq", "ww", "aa", "bb"],
          },
    },
    {
      "test1": {
            "qq": ["11", "22", "33", "44"],
          },
    }
];
```

code

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let list of test">

  <div class="a" (click)="clickEvent(list)" [ngClass]="list.status ? 'blue' : ''">
    {{list.test1.qq[0]}}
    </div>

  <div class="a" (click)="clickEvent(list)" [ngClass]="list.status ? 'blue' : ''">
    {{list.test1.qq[1]}}
    </div>
</ng-container>
```

ts

```
status: boolean = false;
clickEvent(list){
    list.status = !list.status;       
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-skdlf2?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

[image]

Now I click 'qq', 'ww' will also toggle class

But I just want to toggle a class on single div.

Click 'qq', Only 'qq' toggle class

How to do it?

Comment: This is a terrible example to learn. But to explain it to you, you're iterating over a list, and binding the status to that list. Since you display two items from the same iteration, clicking on one result in the other one having the same result, because of the same condition. If you add a third list item, then you will have the same issue on 3 items. Consider binding the status to the final items, not the list itself.

Comment: What is the logic behind toggle? Or just next div?

Comment: you are looping the ng-container that contains two div elements. So technically you are clicking on the ng-container and list item you are clicking on is the same for each div in each iteration, so this is the very reason this is happening. try using only one div in ng-container.

Comment: Unrelated, but you should use `[class.blue]="list.status"` instead of `[ngClass]="list.status ? 'blue' : '' "`. It's more readable and you can toggle multiple independant css classes that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the structure of your array, you might need to pass the targeted item to the click handler. Which in your case `list.test1.qq[1]` or `list.test1.qq[0]`.

Then you might need to separately tell your component which item is clicked, because the targeted item in your case is a string.

In my working solution, I've just defined a string called `clicked` which will memorize and toggle the targeted item and passed the targeted item to the click handler.

[My Working Soulution on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jqxmqj)

Comment: Thanks. But have a little bug. If have the same string, it will be wrong.

Comment: Could you please be more spacific and give an example about that little bug?

Comment: test = [
    {
      "test1": {
            "qq": ["qq", "ww", "aa", "bb"],
          },
    },
    {
      "test1": {
            "qq": ["11", "qq", "33", "44"],
          },
    }
  ]

Comment: like that.If have two "qq" click one both "qq" will toggle

Comment: Yea, in this case you might need to use the items index to avoid this situation.
Here i have the working soultion: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jqxmqj

Answer (score 2):

The *ngFor do not create multiple instances, you have actually only one instance. So if you change the `status` all your divs will change.

The solution is to create a childComponent, the *ngFor will iterate and create as many component instance as items.

With that, every component (item) will have it own status.

I hope this will help !

Answer (score 0):

```js
<div class= "container">
<li *ngFor="let list of test"></li>

  <div class="a" (click)="clickEvent(list)" [ngClass]="list.status ? 'blue' : ''">
    {{list.test1.qq[0]}}
    </div>

  <div class="a" (click)="clickEvent(list)" [ngClass]="list.status ? 'blue' : ''">
    {{list.test1.qq[1]}}
    </div>
</div>
```