# angular 8 how to change class of 1 div instead of all in ngFor loop on click

Tags: angular, class, onclick, indexof

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55122165/angular-toggle-class-only-on-single-div/55122447) is the closest question I could find to what I'm asking but they manually apply the index and have multiple elements while I do not.

Is there a way to change the specific element's `class` in the component?

**html**

here I get the id from the clicked item just fine, but I change the class on click, completing a task. When I click the complete button, all tasks in the loop return completed. I'm not sure how to use `i` here effectively because onclick I'm also sending a put request so I can't add more info to the function without also sending to the database where I don't need it...

`<tr *ngFor="let task of tasks; let i = index;">`

```
<button mat-button
            class="btn"
            [ngClass]="status ? 'btn-lemon-complete' : 'btn-lemon'"
            [disabled]="status ? true : false"
            (click)="completeTask(task._id)"
            >{{ status ? 'Completed' : 'Complete Task' }}</button>

            <button mat-button
            class="btn delete"
            *ngIf="status"
            >✘</button>
```

**component**

```
completeTask(taskId, data): any {
    this.status = true;
    this.triggerService.updateTask(taskId, data).subscribe(res => {
    });

    let item = taskId;
    let index = this.tasks.indexOf(taskId);
    console.log(item, index, this.tasks);
}
```

`console.log(item, index, this.tasks);` returns `id, -1, [0{task here}1{task here}]`

I think I'm getting the `-1` because the actual _id field is in position -1 of the single task I click.

How can I achieve what I'm trying to? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with this solution

**component.html**

```
<button mat-button
    class="btn"
    [ngClass]="task.status ? 'btn-lemon-complete' : 'btn-lemon' "
    [disabled]="task.status ? false : true"
    (click)="completeTask(task)"
>
{{ task.status ? 'Completed':'Complete Task' }}
</button>
```

**component.ts**

```
completeTask(task, data?): any {
    this.triggerService.updateTask(task._id, data).subscribe(res => {
    });
    task.status=true;
}
```

**EDIT**- Passed task from html, made second param optional

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/how-can-i-change-the-color-of-the-active-block?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Yes, thank you!! I just learned how to bind it to the string instead, too since it was in my database as a string not a boolean. Very interesting!

Answer (score 0):

You can try class binding:

```
[class.btn-lemon-complete]="status"
```

link to docs: https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#class-binding

Comment: The class changes just fine this way though, I only want to change it for the task I clicked instead of ALL tasks

Comment: Add a property to that task and use that instead of status. toggle that property when clicking. toggle it back when done.